# How do I use scipy.stats.binned_statistic?

Tags: python, scipy, binning

So I have this csv file with a little more than 16k rows and I want to bin average them, the data are temperature and depth data, so I want to make depth bins 0-10, than 10-20 and so on with the temperature means in them.

My idea is to see something like this:

| depth | temperature |
| --- | --- |
| 5 | 20 |
| 10 | 23 |
| 15 | 27 |

I tried this:

`binned_data = scipy.stats.binned_statistic(data['temperature'], data['pressure'], statistic='mean', bins=1636)

print(binned_data)`

and the output I got was this:

`BinnedStatisticResult(statistic=array([        nan,         nan,         nan, ..., 20.48083333, 13.84529412, 14.27548387]), bin_edges=array([ 2.95      ,  2.96304401,  2.97608802, ..., 24.26391198, 24.27695599, 24.29      ]), binnumber=array([1636, 1635, 1636, ..., 1542, 1543, 1543]))`

I don't know if I understood this scipy function wrong, but how can I see each bin with the corresponding temperature mean as I intended?

Comment: Have you looked at the various examples at the bottom of https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.binned_statistic.html ? I always recommend that you should Read The Fine Manual.

Comment: Please edit your question to address the following: 1) it sounds like you want to bin by depth, but you are passing pressure to `binned_statistic`. 2) you said you want depth binned in increments of 10, but then you expect to see depths 5, 10, 15, etc. 3) there are NaNs in the output, but you didn't mention that there were NaNs or missing values in the raw data. with the information available, I'm guessing you need to reverse the order in which you pass the temperature and depth arguments, and you may need to use np.nanmean as the statistic.

Comment: the thing is, there are none NaNs and the depth is derived from pressure so I just wrote this code using pressure to send the question

Comment: If you want to customize the bins you're using, you can use `bins=[0, 0.5, 1]`, for example, to use two bins from 0 to 0.5 and from 0.5 to 1, for example. bins=1636 will create 1636 equally spaced bins, which is probably not what you want.